# Model Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia.
Em preciso inserir/atualizar os dados de uma tabela do meu banco, porém eu não sei as coluna que podem conter dentro dessa tabela, pois o sistema é muito flex. Criei uma modal com `$fillable = ['*'];` para tentar atualizar apenas os casos que passar no input, mas não está inserindo nada. Segue os códigos abaixo.
Obs: os mesmos dados dos inputs são os dados da tabela.

Modal:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Request;

class ChamadosChamados extends Model
{
protected $table = 'chamados_chamados';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = ['*'];
}
```

DD do input.

```
array:15 [▼
"_token" => "J05hMfB9PtZ6uoVdpKPNc29mZcN4KXgqkpVn71Y0"
"equipe" => "SANTANDER - RCI MOROSO"
"tipo" => "1"
"categoria" => "1"
"modelo_formulario" => "1"
"segmento" => "LEVES PR"
"dias_atraso" => "1"
"contrato" => "1"
"nome_financiado" => "1"
"endereco_financiado" => "1"
"uf" => "PA"
"cidade" => "AURORA"
"telefone_acordo" => "1"
"telefone_agendamento" => "1"
"observacao_required" => "1"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser fazer todos os atributos atribuíveis em massa, você pode definir a propriedade `$guarded` como uma matriz vazia:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Enquanto `$fillable` serve como uma "lista branca" de atributos que devem ser atribuídos em massa, você também pode optar por usar `$guarded`. A propriedade `$guarded` deve conter uma série de atributos que você **não** quer que seja atribuível em massa. Todos os outros atributos  na matriz não serão atribuíveis em massa. Então, `$guarded` funciona como uma "lista negra". Claro, você deve usar qualquer um `$fillable` ou `$guarded` - não ambos.

Fora isso confere a primaryKey da tabela e veja se não precisa definir no model também.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'sua _chave_primaria';
```

Comment: Fechou amigo, fiz como você falou. Passei o $guarded vazio e agora está inserindo e atualizando apenas os casos que estão no formulário. Valeu